# Shellscript action if two files are different

Tags: bash, shell, scp

I am importing a file to my server using this command:

```
scp zumodo@shold:/test/test/test/server.py /test/test/test/test.py~/;
```

I want to restart my server if the newly imported file test.py~ differs from the test.py that already exists. How would I do this using a shellscript?

Comment: I hope you mean "restart my daemon" not "restart my server"

Comment: You probably don't want the final '/;' on that command, because it's not a directory and you don't have another command on the same line.

Comment: @peter do you mean if a load of files is different to one file and check each one? in your comment on my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could diff() the two files.  A return code of zero (0) means there are no differences.  A return code of one (1) says the files differ.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Again I am a novice, do you think you provide me an example or a link to an example?

Comment: @peter see my answer for example/link.

Comment: Why use diff when `cmp` is built for this?

Answer (score 65):

```
if ! cmp -s test.py test.py~
then
  # restart service
fi
```

Breaking that down:

- `cmp -s test.py test.py~` returns true (0) if test.py and test.py~ are identical, else false (1).  You can see this in `man cmp`. The `-s` options makes `cmp` silent, so it doesn't give any output (except errors), but only an exit code.
- `!` inverts that result, so the `if` statement translates to "if test.py and test.py~ are different".

ps: If you are not sure the 2nd file exists, you may want check that too. (`cmp` still works in this case, but gives an error message, suppressing error message may be enough too (`cmp ... 2>/dev/null`)

Comment: +1, but -q is non-standard.  Redirect to /dev/null will always work.

Comment: Sorry, could someone explain the first line for a bash noob? What is the precedance for the argument of the if operator? Why are there those two redirects and what do they mean?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman: Thanks, I used in a script. If I understand this, the Boolean output and the stdout are both sent to the if, so to just have the boolean answer, you have to send the stdout to the bit bucket.

Comment: `if` always uses just the exit status (0/1) of the command. stdout will go to the terminal, so the redirects just make that be quiet.

Comment: You could also use `cmp -s` to suppress terminal output of the comparison.

Comment: Why does bash's if treat a return (0) as true, and (1) as false?  Isn't that counter-intuitive to conventional boolean logic?

Comment: @PolyBug: Yes, it is, but it's the convention in Unix/Linux.  The reason is that there's only one type of success, but there can be many types of failure, which can return different status codes.  See for example the Exit Status sections of `man ls` or `man grep`.

Comment: This will be correct even if the file/files do not exists.

Answer (score 1):

diff <path_to_file_1> <path_to_file_2> && echo "files are same"

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like

```
zumodo@shold$ cat /test/test/test/server.py | ssh zumodo@otherhost 'cat - > /test/test/test/test.py.new ; cmp /test/test/test/test.py /test/test/test/test.py.new || (mv /test/test/test/test.py.new /test/test/test/test.py ; echo issue restart command here)'
```